# Drag and drop for child rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When I drag **Parent_1**,I am expecting the output like below image.

[image: Drag Drop for child rows]

How to achieve this using jquery.

Comment: Please add the relevant source code in your question.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/omipuy/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: You should add the code itself, not a link to it.

Comment: Please explain in detail what you mean by "is not working".

Comment: @user1495394 It is unclear what is not working. Also you have a lot of weird orphaned tags in your HTML. Please clarify.